# How to launch an application with admin rights in c++?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need to do some registry operations & other system operations for that i need admin permission. currently user have to start my application as "Run as administrator".

so How could i launch my application with admin rights?

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666672/forcing-my-mfc-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-vista

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8915744/588306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) or [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431.aspx) is the main thing you need. For `CreateProcessAsUser`, you'll need to use a few other things to make it do its tricks though (e.g., [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx) to enable the privileges it uses, and [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) to get a user's token).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() for this purpose. This routine expects a SHELLEXECUTEINFO structure to be passed to it. The relevant attribute of this structure is "lpverb" which has to be set to a value "runas". This will ensure that the task that is run with elevated priveleges.

Answer (score 1):

The answers deal with starting it programatically, but if the program's entire purpose is to run as admin to make these changes, you can add an [appropriate manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916084/588306) to make Windows elevate for you.

Answer (score 0):

If just part of your application needs admin access, look at [COM elevation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).